# How to make use of cookies while still using oauth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Currently we have a SPA and API and SPA sends email/password to API and API returns response with two secure / HttpOnly / Lax cookies. First cookie is access token with short TTL (custom JWT is stored inside cookie) and second one is a refresh token with long TTL. SPA makes requests to API with those cookies, and API verifies if access token is expired and refreshes it when needed by reading refresh token from cookie and setting new access token cookie.

Because we will have more API clients soon (mobile app and machine-to-machine clients) we wanted to make use of OAUTH to standarize authorization. After making some research it seems that OAUTH is good for everything except SPAs because storing refresh tokens in browser is not secure and should be avoided. For mobile it seems to be secure-enough because refresh token can be stored in OS keychain or something like that.

So it would be reasonable to still use secure cookies for SPA and access tokens for mobile and machine-to-machine. To make it consistent we would like to just have regular oauth access / refresh tokens stored inside cookies and on API side treated in a same way that bearer tokens passed in authorization header. Our SPA and API are in same domain  (different subdomains) and this is more about one API and many clients case.

We are considering following options for SPA:

1. Just use Resource Owner Password Flow - while it's not recommended, it can be used from highly trusted "client" - in our case that would be SPA sending credentials to API and API calling oauth server (with client id, secret and user credentials) to get access token and refresh token and then return those tokens in secure cookies back to SPA.
2. I am not sure if this is possible but I was thinking of splitting Authorization Code Flow between SPA and API. SPA redirects to oauth authorization page, user logins on hosted login page and is redirected back to SPA with authorization code. Then SPA instead of calling /oauth/token on oauth server it sends authorization code to API and API makes final call to /oauth/token on oauth server to get access token and refresh token and store it in cookies. Does it reduce security in any way?

Are there any other options?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for both of your option 2s, though there are some subtleties in getting an SPA and API solution working. These should be the end results:

- In the browser you use HTTP Only SameSite=strict cookies
- You can develop in technologies such as React
- Web and mobile clients can call the same API routes
- SPA can be deployed to a CDN if you prefer

At Curity we have sone detailed resources on this approach, which we call the [Token Handler Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/the-token-handler-pattern/). It is basically just website security via an API. I provided an architectural overview a while back in [this blog post](https://curity.io/blog/token-handler-the-single-page-applications-new-bff/).

It is a tricky flow in deployment terms though, so maybe have a look at the [React SPA Example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/). Note also that this will work with any OAuth provider and is a design pattern, not a vendor solution.

Comment: Interesting, some sources say that tokens should not be stored in local storage and other say it's perfectly fine. For example Auth0 states "You Can Store Refresh Token In Local Storage" (source: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/). They have refresh token re-use detection and rotation so refresh token can be used only once and if it's used more than once it is invalidate as other refresh tokens derived from it. BFF looks little more secure for sure but as you said it complicates things and there is no ready-to-use solution in opposite to OAUTH servers.

Comment: Question: in this BFF solution why it's needed in front of the API? Can't cookie just contain access token and API will handle this cookie, extract access token and validate it (assuming access token is signed JWT)? Or is it something with domains that prevents such cookie usage?

Comment: Perceptions about tokens in the browser have changed a lot over the last year or so. Have a look at [this video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html) which discusses RTs in the browser.

Comment: It is best hosting security practice to put a reverse proxy in front of APIs. You can potentially deal with cookies in APIs directly, though it adds complexity to your code - but do this if it's easier for you. At Curity though we generally recommend doing things like cookie translation in the reverse proxy.

Comment: Actually our API is an API gateway (GQL) that communicates with internal services through GRPC. So can this API GW be treated as a reverse-proxy and deal with cookies? Or would be better to have a reverse proxy in front of the API GW - not an overkill?

Comment: Sorry - I use reverse proxy and API gateway interchangeably - see if you can implement plumbing in the gateway. We do lots of things here - see our [API Gateway Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/apigateway/) for some example patterns.

Comment: @user606521, don't listen to those "localstorage is fine" advices, no matter how respectable those "experts" are, the reasonings are faulty. It DOES matter, if secrets are stealable during an XSS or not. In the simplest case, when the auth server is used for 1st party authentication, and it's on a sibling subdomain as the API server and the CDN SPA, then the auth server can simply put a secure cookie, and problem is solved. Instead of sending back the access token in a hash to the redirect url, it can send an "OK" in the hash to let the app know that the authentication was successful.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Using resource owner password credentials (ropc)**

Avoid ROPC grant. This grant was intended for legacy solutions and security best practice RFCs for OAuth discourage the usage (ex:- [rfc6819 :section-4.4.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.3), [draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-19 :section-2.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-19#section-2.4) ) . Further, this will get deprecated with [OAuth 2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1/)

**2. Split solution - SPA with Backend**

You already have cookies and I assume they get initiated with some validations (ex:- valid access token to establish a cookie) from a backend. Hence, if your application architecture supports or can be modified to support backend based token obtaining (instead of front end only authorization code flow), go for that solution.

*Advantage* - You do not store any token in the browser and tokens can be stored in a secure backend. Cookie expiry can be mapped to token lifetime.

**3. Pure SPA : Session storage or local storage**

If you cannot have the backend for SPA and if you do not want to preserve long lived refresh token (ex:- remember me sort of feature), you can use session storage or local storage (depending on the UX & security requirement).

Things to consider here is *proper management of tokens stored in browser storage* (ex:- clear local storage when SPA exit) & refresh of access token when API returns the 401. Further, use short lived refresh tokens.

Comment: I checked how heroku.com handles it and it seems they just store both access token and refresh token in local storage and don't care about any XSS. And it seems they could use cookies for that, wondering why they don't do this...

Comment: IMO it purely boils down to application architecture & UX requirements. With regards to security, both cookies and localstorage usages must follow security best practices (ex:- CSP headers, httponly cookie and so on). In any case, compromised client will defeat all security aspects.